# Large CSS circles jagged on iphone/ipad

Tags: html, css, iphone, ipad

I have a website with multiple large circles (+/- 5000px). The design looks nice, especially on certain iphone/ipads (iphone 6S plus/ iphone 6S / Ipad third generation). It seems to be the newer generation apple devices. But it is not noticeable on imacs.

Ugly jagged effect on iphone/ipad newer generations:
[image]

Here is my code snippet.

```css
.circle {
    width: 4000px;
    height: 4000px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #314d5c;
    position:absolute;
    left: -90%;
    top: -10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

The circles need to be around 5000px in width/height. The larger the circles, the more noticeable the jadgged effect. And that is not what i like. How can i fix this strange issue?